# How to remove a word in a column which lies between two exact words

Tags: mysql, database

In a Mysql database table, The example row of a column looks like below,

```
/town=xxx/area=yyy/street=zzz/apartment_name=aaa/doorno=bbb
```

How to remove the word in between /street/ and /doorno/. So my expected output should be shown below,

```
/town=xxx/area=yyy/street=zzz/doorno=bbb
```

Comment: I think you should provide a representative data set and a desired result

Comment: @Strawberry K lets this format should be like  `/town=xxx/area=yyy/street=zzz/apartment_name=aaa/doorno=bbb` Then how to remove the word   which starts with '/apartment_name=' and before the patten '/doorno='. and the expected output should be `/town=xxx/area=yyy/street=zzz/doorno=bbb`

Comment: Please edit your question and confirm whether or not your data set comprises of exactly one row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL gives many useful String function e.g. LOCATE(), POSTION, SUBSTR, SUBSTRING etc.
Refer to  : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html

Query Solution to given Problem :

select concat ((SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX('/town=xxx/area=yyy/street=zzz/apartment_name=aaa/doorno=bbb','/',4)),
 (select SUBSTR('/town=xxx/area=yyy/street=zzz/apartment_name=aaa/doorno=bbb',
(select POSITION((SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX('/doorno','/',4)) IN "/town=xxx/area=yyy/street=zzz/apartment_name=aaa/doorno=bbb")),100)
))

Comment: Thanks for ur response

Comment: Welcome, please let me know if you find any other issue on MySql